# Implementation of wait statement inside a fork join block

Tags: system-verilog

what modification is needed to display i value =5,2,7? I am not getting output. Any suggestion will be helpful.

```
module tb#(int T=8);
  bit [8:0] abc;

  initial
    begin
      for(int i=0; i<T; i++)
      begin
        fork
          begin
           wait(abc[i] == 1'b1);
         $display(i,$time);
         end
        join_none
      end
  end
  
  initial
    begin
      abc[5] = 1'b1;
      #10 abc[2] = 1'b1;
      abc[7] = 1'b1;
    end
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/JUZR

Answer (score 0):

There is only one instance of the variable `i` and it's value is 8 by the point in time that the process begins. You need to declare a variable `k` that has a different value for each iteration of the loop.

```
module tb#(int T=8);
  bit [8:0] abc;
  initial
    begin
      for(int i=0; i<T; i++)
      begin
        automatic int k = i;
        fork
          begin
            wait(abc[k] == 1'b1);
            $display(i,k,,,$time);
         end
        join_none
      end
  end
  
  initial
    begin
      abc[5] = 1'b1;
      #10 abc[2] = 1'b1;
      abc[7] = 1'b1;
    end
endmodule
```

See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/fork-joinnone-inside-loop